# how to apply amazon polly service on my web page?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-polly

how to apply Amazon Polly on my web page?
I'm developing a web page which can help people who want to learn English...
so I want to apply Amazon Polly on my web page so 
when people study English sentence like "I like apple", they can listen to the pronunciation of the sentence

I'm developing my web page with jsp
and I don't use any framework

please give me some information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Amazon Polly documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/what-is.html) explains how to use the service.

Basically, your back-end application needs to make a request to Polly by sending some text and identifying the language and voice to use. Polly will then return an **MP3 file**.

Please note that your *application* calls Polly, not your web page.

For **interactive voice application**, you can call Polly on-demand.

If all of your speech is **pre-determined** such that everybody sees the same text, then you can convert the text to MP3 files ahead of time and store them on your application. Then, simply provide the MP3 file to each user when they use that page. This is **cheaper**, because you are charged for the amount of text that is converted but you only need to convert each piece of text once, yet you can play the MP3 file as many times as you wish without calling Polly again.

Comment: oh... thanks to save mp3 files in my application is better for me